# Неправильно отображается кириллицы при чтении из файла

Tags: utf-8, кодировка, python-3.7

```
fhand = open("text.txt")  
for line in fhand:  
    print(line)
```

В файле text.txt слово "**привет**". При запуске скрипта вывод в консоли: "**Р±Р»СЏС‚СЊ**" .
В самом терминале кириллица отображается нормально. Так же обычная команда print('**Привет**') выводит в терминале "**Привет**". Почему при чтении кириллицы из файла ломается кодировка, и как можно исправить?
Кодировка в терминале UTF-8

Comment: Имеет значение в какой кодировке текст хранится в файле. Например, под windows функция open будет пытаться открыть файл в кодировке win1251. Если у вас файл сохранен в другой кодировке, то чтении из файла вы получите не то что хотели увидеть. Нужно уточнить в какой кодировке сохранен файл, и при открытии файла указать ее: `fhand = open("text.txt", encoding='utf-8')`

Comment: @insolor Спасибо, помогло. Можно ли каким-то способом указать кодировку один раз, например в начале файла. В том случае, если нужно будет открывать много файлов?

Comment: Я не вижу проблемы в том, чтобы каждый раз указывать кодировку явно ("явное лучше неявного"). Теоретически дефолтную кодировку поменять можно, но я сейчас сходу не нашел как (узнать можно через `locale.getpreferredencoding()`).